# Helping my girlfriend move to Poland

Tags: visa, immigration, marriage, poland

I'm looking for some answers/advice about the topic mentioned in the title.

I come from Poland and I currently live, study and work there too. I've been in a long-distance relationship for almost 2 years now with a girl from Philippines. I've met her last summer, we took a lot of pictures together. Besides that we've sent a lot of letters and gifts to each other. She studied medicine but sadly the situation at her home went really downhill and she was forced to stop studying and will be most likely forced to work.

I want to help her move to me and live with me. I earn enough to cover the costs of me and her living together. I've done a lot of research about how to grant her rights to extend her stay here, so I think that it shouldn't be a problem, in contrast to her getting a visa.

She is unemployed and stopped studying. I want to help her move here legally. We both decided that we want to get married. The only problem is how to do this within the immigration rules. I thought that travel visa is what she needs, but I'm not sure. How can I help her come to Poland?

Comment: I don't know much about how this works in Poland, but I am familiar with other countries.  The UK and the US require a specific fiancée visa if someone wants to enter the country for the purpose of marrying and staying.  Another option is to get married elsewhere and then get a spouse visa.  If you move to another EU country, that's the easiest way to go, because of EU free movement rights. But as a Pole in Poland, EU law does not apply to you, so the requirements may be more stringent.

Comment: I've done a lot of research and I'm almost certain that Poland doesn't offer a fiancee visa. I thought that she could come with a tourist visa and stay residence permit based on marriage, but i was advised against getting a tourist visa for that purpose.

Comment: Well who gave you that advice?  For all I know, that might be the proper way to go about it under Polish law, and the advice was given without any knowledge of Polish law, simply because one definitely shouldn't use a tourist visa for that purpose in several other countries.  If I have some time I'll try to look it up, but you might try it yourself by going to a Polish embassy web site and looking for information about visas.